# How to insert the value entered in <input type="time"/> into database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an htmlcode which contains an . I have entered a value like "01:00 AM" in the input field. When I am inserting the entered time value into the database table, only "01:00" is getting inserted , "AM" is not getting inserted into database. I have used the datatype "varchar(20)" for the time field in database table.Can anyone tell how to insert the full time with AM and PM into database ?

```
       html:
              <form action="projectinser.php" method="post">
                   <div id="dynamicInput" style="display:inline" >
                <input type="text" name="itemname"  pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="Item" value="" size="35">
                    </div>
                    <div id="dynamicInput1" style="display:inline">
                      <input type="text" name="sdate" id="datepicker" placeholder="Enter Start Date" value="" size="34">
                     </div>
                    <div id="dynamicInput" style="display:inline">
                 <input type="time" name="stime" placeholder="Enter Time"  
             value="" size="34">
              </div>
         <div id="dynamicInput2" style="display:inline">
             <input type="text" name="details"  pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="Enter Details" value="" size="34">
             </div>
        </form>

           projectinser.php
            <?php
           $itemname = $_POST['itemname'];
            $sdate    = $_POST['sdate']; 
            $details  = $_POST['details'];
            $stime = $_POST['stime'];

           $sql= "INSERT INTO projectdetail (projectid, item, remainderdate, time, details) VALUES ('$cid', '$itemname', '$sdate', '$stime', '$details')";
            mysqli_query($con,$sql);
           ?>
```

Comment: Share your code ? HTML and mysql query both

Comment: My answer should work for you.  I'll update it to include your actual code

Comment: @anna : Is your input _<input type="time"/>_  tag working in all browser ? Which browser you are using now ?

Comment: @anna yes, I recommend changing the type="time" to type="text"

Comment: if i changed type="text" what should be the datatype of time field in the database table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the type to **type="text"** should fix this as you are using varchar for the table.

```
<input type="text" name="stime" placeholder="Enter Time"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do two things.  You could change your column to an actual DATETIME or TIME field.  That way it will store the time as a real time format.

Or you could do this when you insert.

```
$input = $_POST['input'];
$the_time = date('h:i A', strtotime($input));
```

I've provided a sample here, with 3 examples, of time stamps being converted to your wanted format.

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/933631e27d530337ef601ef8238d0fb341dba6ed)
 I do however, suggest storing them as actual timestamps, that way you can manipulate them in the future if needed

Update: (to include your code)

```
 $stime = $_POST['stime'];
 $the_time = date('h:i A', strtotime($stime));

 $sql= "INSERT INTO projectdetail (projectid, item, remainderdate, time, details) VALUES ('$cid', '$itemname', '$sdate', '$the_time', '$details')";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```